# Fetch non-int (string) url resource-id in crow

Tags: c++, rest, c++11, flask, crow

How to get a non-int resource-id in c++ [crow](https://github.com/ipkn/crow). I cannot add a route
`CROW_ROUTE(app, "/uid/<std::string>")` or `CROW_ROUTE(app, "/uid/<char*>")` as it fails to compile. The [examples](https://github.com/ipkn/crow/tree/master/examples) donot have such a case. I have tried

```
int main() {
    crow::SimpleApp app;
    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/uid/*").methods("GET"_method)
    ([](const crow::request& req){
        return "hello";
        });

    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/uid/<int>").methods("GET"_method)
    ([](const crow::request& req, int id){
        return std::to_string(id);
        });
    app.port(8888).run();
}
```

But neither of them ( though correctly ) intercept `GET /uid/uid_123 HTTP/1.1` ( with resource being a string `"uid_123"` )

For below python code, I want to acheive it in c++ crow library

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/uid/<path:path>")
def hello1(path):
    print ("it is path is ", path)
    return "user id is -" + path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8888)
```

Is there any workaround for the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally answered by [erow](https://github.com/erow) and [jihoo](https://github.com/jjhoo) on [github](https://github.com/)

```
CROW_ROUTE(app,"/uid/<path>")
    ([](std::string path){
     return path;
     });
```

In addition to `int` and `path` following also work :`uint`, `double` and `string`